# DJANGO cors is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: django, cors

Access to XMLHttpRequest at '[http://ка.ко.й.тоip:порт/ссылка](http://%D0%BA%D0%B0.%D0%BA%D0%BE.%D0%B9.%D1%82%D0%BEip:%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82/%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Answer (score 4):

Ошибка происходит из-за того, что политика [CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) в браузере по-умолчанию запрещает делать кросс-доменные запросы, чтобы с клиентской стороны domain-1.com не шли запросы, например, к API на domain-2.com. Чтобы разрешить это действие, вы можете "сказать вашему серверу" посылать специальные headers, которые разрешат эти действия. Проще всего в django сделать это так, как описано ниже.

**Решение**

Добавьте в ваш файл requirements.txt `django_cors_headers` или выполните `pip install django-cors-headers`

Далее в конфигурации django приложения добавьте

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)
```

и

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

**Важно!** Настройка `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` должна быть как можно выше в списке `MIDDLEWARE`

И в конце добавьте в файл конфигурации django приложения

`CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`

Более подробно смотрите [тут](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/)

А что такое CORS и для чего он нужен можете посмотреть [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Answer (score 1):

мне помогло

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
        ...
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло

```
 CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

 CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
 ]
```

в файле settings.py