# Запрос к серверу при помощи axios

Tags: axios, vue-cli

Есть абсолютно пустой проект на vue-cli, я пытаюсь понять как с помощью axios сделать запрос к серверу для получения данных. Перерыв несколько десятков сайтов и форумов пришёл к такой схеме:

Подключаю axios в main.js таким образом (на всякий случай предоставлю весь код):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Теперь в App.vue пытаюсь получить данные с сервера (Сервер запущен локально, для отдачи данных используется Django rest framework). И так, App.vue:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
  },
  mounted() {
    this.axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/?format=json').then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Я получаю такую ошибку в console log:
*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/?format=json' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*
В логах django даже нет попытки запроса данных, т.е. запроса к серверу не произошло, но если я пытаюсь получить данные не с локального сервера, а, например, с https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, то всё отлично работает, вопрос из-за чего возникает ошибка и как её обойти, я также пробовал запускать сервер на django не на том же ip, а на 192.168.0.79:8000, результат тот же.
P.S. Я новичок во vue, можно забрасывать тухлыми помидорами
P.P.S. Если нужно больше кода, предоставлю

Comment: Порывшись немного в интернете и погуглив проблему я понял, что запрос всё-таки происходит и проблема не во vue, a в Django, который не отдаёт небходимый header

Comment: Проблема была решена так при помощи похожего вопроса:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/901351/django-cors-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-headers